# Can the sum of two divergent geometric series converge such that none of the terms is zero?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

So yes i was solving an exercise and i want to split the sum. And i was questioning myself if i can do that ?

for example

$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(2^i-1)x^i$ and splitting
$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(2x)^i$$-$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^i$
and saying now that it converges for every $|x|<1/2$ What would be incorrect about this or how could i argument if it was correct ?

Comment: So, you want to test the series $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(2^i-1)x^i$?

Comment: no i know how to test that, i just want to know if im allowed to do that what i did in the example.

Comment: Sorry, I was not looking at the title completely... Ignore my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see there is a bounty for this question, but what question? The title says "Can the sum of two divergent geometric series converge such that none of the terms is zero?" and I see that it was already answered by Chris Sanders. In the text there is perhaps a more general question: "...  I want to split the sum. And i was questioning myself if i can do that ?".  A question regarding series in general, not just geometric series.

In general, the sum of two convergent series is a convergent series. If 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n = A $$
and 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n = B$$
then
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(a_n + b_n \right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n = A+B$$
If one of the two series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n $ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n $  is convergent and the other is not convergent, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(a_n + b_n \right)$ is not convergent.

If both series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n $ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n $  are not convergent, nothing can be said about $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(a_n + b_n \right)$

In your exercise, both power series $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(2x)^i$ and   $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^i$ are convergent for  $|x|<1/2$, so
also $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(2^i-1)x^i=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(2x)^i-\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^i$ is convergent for  $|x|<1/2$.

For  $1/2<|x|<1$,  $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^i$ is convergent, but $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(2x)^i$ is not, so $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(2^i-1)x^i$ is not convergent.

For $|x| > 1$, both power series $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(2x)^i$ and   $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^i$ are not convergent, but this does not imply that $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(2^i-1)x^i$ is not convergent. 
However we know that the set of convergence of a power series is an interval  , therefore, if there were some $x_0$ such that $|x_0| > 1$ and $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(2^i-1)x_0^i$ is convergent, then the series would be convergent for $|x| < |x_0|$, so it would be convergent also for $1/2<|x|<1$, but this contradicts what we proved before. The power series $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(2^i-1)x^i$ is not convergent for $|x| > 1$.

Conclusion: the power series $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(2^i-1)x^i$ is convergent for  $|x|<1/2$.

.

Comment: I would like the second question answered. I thought that if my title question would be answered it would answer the question whether i can split the sums. (maybe im wrong)

Comment: because both series are geometriv series

Comment: I edited may previous answer, I hope it answers the more general question.

Comment: so you mean my argumentation is incorrect ? i cannot split $(2^i -1)x^i$ ? to find the convergence radius ?

Comment: No, I didn't mean that. I did't even examine the geometric series. That's the general theorem. And it says nothing about the convergenge radius, just convergence. If the two geometric series you used to split are both convergent, so it is the original series. If one of them is convergent and the other one is not convergent, the original series is not convergent.If both a re not convergent nothing can be affirmed about the original series.

Comment: I was trying to find out whether this series is convergent. So i transformed it and i split the sum. and found out splitted series are convergent for x<1/2 i was just wondering if im allowed to do that.

Comment: I mean this is all im asking for, maybe i am explaining myself very badly. sorry

Comment: So, if both are convergent, the original series is convergent

Comment: I needed to find out the convergence radius of $\sum (2^i-1)x^i$. This is the question. So what i did is i splitted both. and said both splitted series are convergent for x<1/2. I dont know if this is right though, because the sum of two divergent series can be convergent. So my argument would be incorrect.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. So the question was about the radius of convergence.

Comment: Yes. Im really sorry for asking this question in such an ambiguous way :C

Comment: Now, it was my fault. I read your question again and it's clear. It was me reading too fast.

Answer (score 0):

Show that the power series $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(2^i-1)x^i$ has convergence radius $1/2$. For $|x|<1/2$ we then have

$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(2^i-1)x^i=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(2x)^i-\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^i$ ,

since both power series on the right are convergent for  $|x|<1/2$.

Comment: So you think my reasoning is correct ?

Comment: but $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(2x)^i-\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^i$ doesnt have to converge for its sum to converge

Answer (score 0):

I will answer the question in the title.

Can $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}p^i-q^i$ converge, if $p\neq q$ and $|p|,|q|\geq1$? No.

This is obvious if $p=-q$. Without loss of generality, assume $|p|>|q|$. Then $p^n-q^n$ will eventually exceed $1$ (prove it).